# Allow merging branches only with a specific name

Tags: python, bash, git, shell, githooks

So I want to create some rules/restrictions for my GitHub repo and from what I've read the best way to do that is with git hooks. The restriction that gives me a hard time in creating is the following: I want to block merging any branches into master but the ones that contain "Release" in the name or in other words: allow merging into master only if it's a release branch. I've tried to do a python script but the problem is that `sys.argv` gives me the path to the hook (`.git/hooks/pre-merge-commit`) and not the command arguments, so I don't know how to take the input from the command line in order to verify if is it the right branch

```
#!/bin/python
import sys, subprocess, re

print('inside script')

mergingBranch='Release'
protectedBranch='master'
 
print(len(sys.argv))
```

Comment: I think it would make sense if you also post the code of the _pre-merge-commit_, otherwise it is hard to give an advice.

Comment: From the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_pre_merge_commit) for `pre-merge-commit` hook: "*It takes no parameters, and is invoked after the merge has been carried out successfully and before obtaining the proposed commit log message to make a commit.*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [doc about `pre-merge-commit`](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_pre_merge_commit) states (emphasis mine) :

> **pre-merge-commit**
>
> This hook is invoked by git-merge[1], and can be bypassed with the `--no-verify` option. **It takes no parameters**, and is invoked **after the merge has been carried out successfully and before obtaining the proposed commit log message** to make a commit.

So you will have to look at the state of your repo to get your information :

- you can get the name of the active branch with `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`
- to my knowledge, the *name* of the merged branch is not directly stored in a file,
  the closest thing I know of would be to use :

```sh
git branch --points-at MERGE_HEAD
# or use for-each-ref, which has a stabler output for scripts :
git for-each-ref --points-at MERGE_HEAD
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:lstrip=2)" --points-at MERGE_HEAD
```

If you are running `git merge Release/feature` from `master` :

- the first command should return `master`
- the second one should return `Release/feature`